# ¿Cómo formular la siguiente consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas:

- rutina
- personas
- ejercicios

Las rutinas son 3 y cada una tiene su grupo de ejercicios.

Estas tablas tienen una relación de muchos a muchos mediante una tabla de relaciones llamada `rutinas_has_ejercicios`.

Necesito que la consulta me traiga los tipos de ejercicio de cada rutina para cada usuario.

Este es el `join` que he utilizado, pero a la hora de ejecutar la consulta, me dice:

> table rutinas has ejercicios is not unique

Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios`, `personas`.`idPersonas`, `rutina`.`idRutina`
FROM `ejercicios` , `personas` , `rutina`
LEFT JOIN `rutina_has_ejercicios` ON `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios` = `rutina_has_ejercicios`.`ejercicios_idEjercicios`  AND `rutina_has_ejercicios`.`ejercicios_maquinaria_idMaquinaria` = `ejercicios`.`maquinaria_idMaquinaria` 
LEFT JOIN `rutina_has_ejercicios` ON `rutina`.`idRutina` = `rutina_has_ejercicios`.`rutina_idRutina`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y qué has probado hasta ahora?

Comment: Añadí tu query a la pregunta para que sea más probable de obtener respuesta

Comment: Argh... y yo que te había indentado la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Necesito que la consulta me traiga los tipos de ejercicio de cada
>   rutina para cada usuario.

No sé si esto se aproxima a lo que necesitas.

El `GROUP_CONCAT` da resultados interesantes que luego puedes obtener individualmente si lo deseas haciendo un `split` basado en el separador utilizado, en este caso `|`. Es como tener varias posibles columnas en una sola, lo cual es interesante, sobre todo en posibles resultados más amplios.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11052a/10)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE personas
    (`persona_id` int, `persona_nom` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO personas
    (`persona_id`, `persona_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;


CREATE TABLE historia_clinica
    (`historia_id` int, `persona_id` int, `rutina_id` int )
;

INSERT INTO historia_clinica
    (`historia_id`, `persona_id`, `rutina_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 2),
    (3, 3, 3)
;


CREATE TABLE rutinas
    (`rutina_id` int, `rutina_nom` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO rutinas
    (`rutina_id`, `rutina_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Rutina 1'),
    (2, 'Rutina 2'),
    (3, 'Rutina 3')
;


CREATE TABLE ejercicios
    (`ejercicio_id` int, `ejercicio_nom` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO ejercicios
    (`ejercicio_id`, `ejercicio_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Ejercicio 1'),
    (2, 'Ejercicio 2'),
    (3, 'Ejercicio 3')
;

CREATE TABLE rutinas_has_ejercicios
    (`rutina_id` int, `ejercicio_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO rutinas_has_ejercicios
    (`rutina_id`, `ejercicio_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT p.persona_id, p.persona_nom,
  GROUP_CONCAT(r.rutina_nom, ': ', e.ejercicio_nom SEPARATOR '|') AS rutinas_ejercicios

FROM
  historia_clinica hc
  LEFT JOIN personas p    ON hc.persona_id = p.persona_id
  LEFT JOIN rutinas r    ON hc.rutina_id = r.rutina_id
  LEFT JOIN rutinas_has_ejercicios rhe ON r.rutina_id = rhe.rutina_id
  LEFT JOIN ejercicios e  ON rhe.ejercicio_id = e.ejercicio_id
  GROUP BY p.persona_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11052a/10/0)**:

```
| persona_id | persona_nom |rutinas_ejercicios                                       |
|------------|-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          1 |       Pedro |                       Rutina 1: Ejercicio 1|Rutina 1: Ejercicio 3 |
|          2 |    Santiago |                       Rutina 2: Ejercicio 3|Rutina 2: Ejercicio 2 |
|          3 |        Juan | Rutina 3: Ejercicio 1|Rutina 3: Ejercicio 2|Rutina 3: Ejercicio 3 |
```

Comment: Muchas gracias porfin  entiendo en mis saberes no sabia que podia insertar datos en una tabla de muchos a muchos ni conocia el group concat gracias de verdad eres como mi tutor online!!!

Comment: Gracias  @a-cedano, yo ya había bajado los brazos con esta pregunta

Comment: De nada @SERGIO Me alegro de que te haya servido.

Comment: @amenadiel Gracias también a ti, tu esfuerzo no ha sido en vano. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Sin saber la forma de tus tablas no puedo adivinar, pero el error que te da es correcto. Estás consultando dos veces la misma tabla sin distinguirlas con un alias.

La siguiente consulta no debiese tener ese error

```
SELECT `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios`, 
       `personas`.`idPersonas`, 
        `rutina`.`idRutina`
FROM `ejercicios` , `personas` , `rutina`
LEFT JOIN `rutina_has_ejercicios` rhe1 
     ON `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios` = rhe1.`ejercicios_idEjercicios`  AND rhe1.`ejercicios_maquinaria_idMaquinaria` = `ejercicios`.`maquinaria_idMaquinaria` 
LEFT JOIN `rutina_has_ejercicios` rhe2 
     ON `rutina`.`idRutina` = rhe2.`rutina_idRutina`
```

Pero esto no significa que vaya a darte el resultado que esperas. Sólo basta para salir del primer escollo

Entre las cosas que veo y no entiendo:

- Pienso que falta una tabla de maquinaria, o bien cada ejercicio tiene una sola maquinaria posible. Sea como sea, la tabla `rutina_has_ejercicio` no debiese tener idMaqinaria.
- Si rutina_has_ejercicios está pensada para vincular rutinas y ejercicios, no tiene sentido llamarla dos veces.
- Falta un JOIN entre personas y rutinas, ya sea con una tabla de relaciones o bien asumiendo que cada persona tiene una sola rutina (`persona_has_rutina` tal ves?)

**EDIT**, ahora que vi el esquema. La tabla de relación que me faltaba era la historia clínica. La consulta quedaría así

```
SELECT `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios`, 
       `personas`.`idPersonas`, 
       `rutina`.`idRutina`
FROM personas
LEFT JOIN historia_clinica ON personas.idPersonas = historia_clinica.personas_idPersonas
LEFT JOIN rutina on historia_clinica.rutina_idRutina = rutina.idRutina
LEFT JOIN rutina_has_ejercicios ON rutina_has_ejercicios.idRutina = rutina.idRutina
LEFT JOIN ejercicios ON rutina_has_ejercicios.ejercicios_idEjercicios = ejercicios.idEjercicios
```

(en realidad podrías saltarte el paso por la tabla de rutinas, considerando que tanto la historia clínica como rutina_has_ejercicios tienen un idRutina)

**EDIT2**: para listar las rutinas y sus respectivos ejercicios:

```
SELECT `rutina`.`idRutina`,
       `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios`
FROM rutina           
LEFT JOIN rutina_has_ejercicios ON rutina_has_ejercicios.idRutina = rutina.idRutina
LEFT JOIN ejercicios ON rutina_has_ejercicios.ejercicios_idEjercicios = ejercicios.idEjercicios
```

Comment: Entonces sólo quieres obtener las rutinas y los ejercicios de cada una?

Comment: si los ejercicios ya tienen su id  solo necesito asignarlos a sus respectivas rutinas

Comment: no entiendo exactamente a qué te refieres con "asignarlos". La tabla de relación ya tiene ejercicios y rutinas y quieres listar esa información? O quieres insertar relaciones que todavía no existen?

Comment: listar los ejercicios en cada rutina por ejemplo el administrador asigna la rutina 103 que es para endomorfos y esa rutina muestre los ejercicios correspondientes a esa rutina voy a adjuntar el script

Comment: dejé una tercera query, a ver si era lo que estabas buscando. Probablemente quieras listas no sólo el ID sino el nombre de cada elemento

Comment: hola mira estuve intentado llamarlas pero solo puedo llamar un ejercicio  
 `SELECT `rutina`.`idRutina`, `ejercicios`.`idEjercicios`, `ejercicios`.`Ejercicio`
FROM `ejercicios` , `rutina`
WHERE `rutina`.`idRutina` = (401) and ejercicios.idEjercicios= (301)`